# testinfra - ansible variables not interpreted correctly

Tags: python-3.x, ansible, testinfra

With [testinfra](https://testinfra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), I'm using
`get_variables()` method from [testinfra.modules.ansible.Ansible](https://testinfra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules.html#testinfra.modules.ansible.Ansible) but it seems that **testinfra cannot evaluate my Ansible variable**.

Let's describe my poc.

```
~/tmp/ansible-testinfra
├── inventories
│   ├── group_vars
│   │   └── all.yml
│   └── inventory.ini
└── test_simple.py
```

I defined 2 variables :

```yaml
# inventories/group_vars/all.yml

---
one: "value one"
two: "{{ one }} and value two"
```

and my `inventory.ini` is a simple localhost :

```
# inventories/inventory

[all]
localhost
```

I created a very simple test like this :

```py
# test_simple.py

import pprint

def test_print_variables(host):
    pprint.pprint(host.ansible.get_variables())
    
def test_variables(host):
    my_vars = host.ansible.get_variables()
    assert my_vars['two'] == 'value one and value two'
```

When I run pytest, here is my sdtout :

```
~/tmp/ansible-testinfra$ pytest --hosts "ansible://all?ansible_inventory=inventories/inventory.ini" -s --tb=no
============================================================================ test session starts ============================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.9, pytest-6.2.2, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /home/olhoa/tmp/ansible-testinfra
plugins: testinfra-6.1.0
collected 2 items                                                                                                                                                           

test_simple.py {'group_names': ['ungrouped'],
 'groups': {'all': ['localhost'], 'ungrouped': ['localhost']},
 'inventory_hostname': 'localhost',
 'one': 'value one',
 'two': '{{ one }} and value two'}
.F

========================================================================== short test summary info ==========================================================================
FAILED test_simple.py::test_variables[ansible://localhost] - AssertionError: assert '{{ one }} and value two' == 'value one and value two'
```

As you can see, variable `one` is not interpreted when used in variable `two`.

So, **is this possible to do this and how ?**

Thank you for your feedback ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're testing the inventory. The result is correct

```sh
shell> ansible-inventory -i inventory.ini --graph --vars
@all:
  |--@ungrouped:
  |  |--localhost
  |  |  |--{one = value one}
  |  |  |--{two = {{ one }} and value two}
  |--{one = value one}
  |--{two = {{ one }} and value two}
```

Quoting from [Glossary](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html):

> *Lazy Evaluation: In general, Ansible evaluates any variables in playbook content at the last possible second, which means that if you define a data structure that data structure itself can define variable values within it, and everything “just works” as you would expect. This also means variable strings can include other variables inside of those strings.*

To evaluate the variables in playbook content write one, e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat playbook
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: one
    - debug:
        var: two
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventory.ini

...

TASK [debug] ************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  one: value one

TASK [debug] ************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  two: value one and value two
```

---

As a side note, see [Understanding variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence). In Ansible, the variable precedence is rather complex, e.g.

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventory.ini -e one=X

...

TASK [debug] ************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  one: X

TASK [debug] ************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  two: X and value two
```

Comment: So, there is not an other way to do this except with module debug :( , I'm so disappointed. 

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Not only debug. Any evaluation would do. Make sure you understand [lazy evaluation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html).